# How to install and load the native gpl library gplcompression in Mac in a java application?

Tags: java, macos, lzo

I have a dropwizard application and i use inside the hadoop-lzo lib to decompress some files compressed with lzo. When I use it, it shows this error:

```
ERROR [2017-01-11 09:00:21,887] com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader: Could not load native gpl library
! java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
! at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
! at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
...
```

How can I install the native library gpl compression in mac, and load in the java application?